# Juniper SRX add custom BGP route

Tags: bgp, juniper

I have BGP configured between AzureStack (win2k16) and SRX210. On the Juniper I see all routes advertised but the Juniper is only advertising its physical interface networks.. 
I want the Juniper to also include all static routes that are configured towards the 2k16 machine..

Config NOW (on juniper)

```
policy-statement send-direct {
    term 1 {
        from protocol direct;
        then accept;
    }

group AzureStack {
    type internal;
    multihop {
        ttl 50;
    }
    export send-direct;
    neighbor 172.16.7.14 {
        local-address 172.16.7.1;
        peer-as 65050;
        local-as 65050;
    }
}
```

Received on 2k16

```
DestinationNetwork NextHop

172.16.4.0/29    172.16.7.1  Juniper
172.16.5.0/24    172.16.7.1  Juniper
172.16.6.0/24    172.16.7.1  Juniper
```

But my Juniper for example has a static route to 172.16.8.0/22 which I want to include in the bgp advertisement..

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and is off topic for this site. Delete it.

Comment: This would probably be on-topic for networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You would want to modify your policy to advertise static-routes. Maybe create another term in your policy.

```
set policy-options policy-statement send-direct term2 from protocol static 
set policy-options policy-statement send-direct term2 then accept
```